# CSS set border gradient color

Tags: css

How can make a simple border bottom color with gradient color?

```css
div{
  border-bottom:10px solid linear-gradient(#FF4000, transparent);
  height:20px;
  width:auto;
  background:#ccc;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: you can use `linear-gradient` to achieve the effect. check demo. http://jsbin.com/hanabozace/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Using `:after` pseudo element and `linear-gradient` you can get desire results. Here in this code I am using `background:liner-gradient` on `:after` pseudo element with just using a one single element.

You may have to use browser prefix as well if you targeting older browsers.

Check [Demo](http://jsbin.com/hanabozace/1/edit) as well.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
}
```

```html
<div>Hi</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a border gradient on a single border (or multiple borders), you simply need to declare style rules in your CSS for:

- `border-image`
- `border-image-slice`
- `border-image-width`

```css
.box {
width: auto;
height: 20px;
background: #ccc;
border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 64, 0, 1), rgba(255, 64, 0, 0));
border-image-slice: 1;
border-image-width: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
            
</div>
```

**N.B.** The *fade-to-transparent* gradient is achieved using `rgba colors` (in place of `hex colors`).

`rgba(255, 64, 0, 0)` (with an `alpha channel` of `0`) is the completely transparent equivalent of `rgba(255, 64, 0, 1)` (which, with an `alpha channel` of `1`, is completely opaque).

Answer (score 0):

You can set gradient as border color. But you can do it using another element.

```
<style>
    div {height:20px; background: linear-gradient(#FF4000, transparent); padding-bottom: 10px;}
    div div {background: yellow; padding-bottom: 0;}
</style>
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7et1w393/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 .myClass {
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.33, rgb(14,173,172)), color-stop(0.67, rgb(0,255,255)));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(14,173,172) 50%, rgb(0,255,255) 67% );
padding: 10px;
}

.myClass > div { background: #fff; }
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xyoytt7w/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #3acfd5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%)
```

```css
div {
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00abeb), to(#fff), color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #66cc00)) 21 30 30 21 repeat repeat;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is its a browser specific. Will not work any other browser.

Comment: alternate solution is  -  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #ccc, #ab2f5e,);

Comment: why not using `linear-gradient` at least IE10 support that also.

Comment: ya it is also possible this :-  border-image: linear-gradient(to right,  #000, #ccc, #ab2f5e);